# Why I don't receive proper results by running query in Apache Camel?

Tags: java

MyRouteBuilder.java

```
rom("direct:select")
        .log("============Query to salesforce===========")
        .to("salesforce:query?sObjectQuery=select Id,Name,PSA_Activity_Sequence__c,PSA_Model_Code__c from PSA_Job_Master__c where Name='shai2'&sObjectClass=com.cg.Pojos.PSA_Job_Master__c")
        .log("Received ${headers.CamelSalesforceEventType} notification for ${body.name}")
        .setHeader("CamelFileName", simple("${body.name}"))
        .log("${body}") 
        .to("file:C:/jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084/work/camel-salesforce/output?fileName=${headers.CamelFileName}")
        .log("============send to folder===========")
        .end()
        ;
```

Received result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PSA_Job_Master__c>
    <PSA_Activity_Sequence__c>0</PSA_Activity_Sequence__c>//actually it has value "2" but show "0"
</PSA_Job_Master__c>
```

Expected Result:

```
<PSA_Job_Master__c>
    <id>a0L0k000002GPyQEAW</id>
    <name>shai2</name>
    <PSA_Activity_Sequence__c>1</PSA_Activity_Sequence__c>
    <PSA_Model_Code__c>b</PSA_Model_Code__c>
</PSA_Job_Master__c>
```

and even not getting a specific attribute which is we specify in the query.
This is a REST call.For connection to salesforce 
config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0 https://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.0.0.xsd              http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd              http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint https://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
    <!-- OSGi blueprint property placeholder -->
    <cm:property-placeholder id="placeholder" persistent-id="org.jboss.quickstarts.fuse.salesforce"/>
    <bean
        class="org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.SalesforceComponent" id="salesforce">
        <property name="loginConfig">
            <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.SalesforceLoginConfig">
                <property name="loginUrl" value="${loginUrl}"/>
                <property name="clientId" value="${clientId}"/>
                <property name="clientSecret" value="${clientSecret}"/>
                <property name="userName" value="${userName}"/>
                <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="packages">
            <array>
                <value>com.cg.Pojos</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.jboss.quickstarts.fuse.salesforce.RouteXml" id="data"/>
    <camelContext id="salesforce-example-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <routeBuilder ref="data"/>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please, take a [tour] and read [ask]. Edit your question and provide more details about your Camel config. Also - it would be great if you could provide the result of the query used in you Java code, but run in Salesforce directly.

Comment: @PrzemysławTamoń can u please reply ,if u have any idea about this

Comment: I don't. I only pointed out that your question lacked of necessary details - it could help others who know Apache Camel to solve your problem. Anyway I can try - have you tried to run a query with hardcoded parameters? Instead of ``where Name='shai2'&sObjectClass=com.cg.Pojos.PSA_Job_Master__c`` using ``where Name='PUT_NAME_HERE'``? Also - as I have already mentioned - it would be worth to run the query in SF Developer Console to see if you are actually right that the record should have value of ``2``, instead of ``0``

Comment: actually 'shai2' is hardcoded in that query,i check through workbench of salesforce.it is working fine there.Is there any issue with "salesforce:query" return type bcoz it return totalsize,done and records.in records we have actual data we queried right

Comment: Please run the query once without any where clause. If it runs, we can isolate the issue to where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Actually query return "done" , "totalSize" ,"records" as response .whatever you queried to salesforce query is in the records.To view this you have to add below line and their getter and setter in your class.

private List  records;
and then mapped list of object to appropriate class.

For more details:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm